# Lagrange's theorem shows that $H\cap N = \{e\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is from a past paper with some explanatory answers, however a step has confused me. Here is a bit more context:

$G$ is a finite abelian group with $|G|=35$. We know that $G$ has a normal subgroup $H$ of order $5$, and a normal subgroup $N$ of order $7$. In the explanatory note, the next sentence is:

"Since 5 and 7 are coprimes, we know from Lagrange's theorem that $H \cap N=\{e\}$."

However I can't see how this follows, since we only have Lagrange's theorem in the following form:

Lagrange:

*if* $H \subseteq G$ *is a subgroup of a finite group* $G$*, then* $$|G| = |G/H||H|.$$*The order of a subgroup divides the order of the group.*

How does  $H\cap N = \{e\}$ follow from the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$H\cap N$ is a subgroup of $H$. By Lagrange, $|H\cap N|$ is a factor
of $|H|=5$.

$H\cap N$ is a subgroup of $N$. By Lagrange, $|H\cap N|$ is a factor
of $|N|=7$.

What then is $|H\cap N|$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $H \cap N$ is a subgroup of $H$ and $N$, its order must divide both $|H|$ and $|N|$. And the only number which divides both $7$ and $5$ is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=|H\cap N|$.  Since, $H\cap N$ is a subgroup of both $H$ and $N$, $n|5$ and $n|7$, by Lagrange. But because $(5,7)=1$, we must have $n=1$.

Answer (score 0):

From $|G|=|G/H||H|$ you can deduce that the order oh $H$ divides the order of $G$. So, the order of $H\cap N$ divided both the orders of $H$ and $N$. Since $H$ and $N$ are relatively prime, the order of $H\cap N$ must be $1$.